# xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync not working

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

I am using `Sitecore Connect for Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Sales 2.0.1` . I am trying to run `xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync` this pipeline but it is showing me 
below output in log file:

```
ManagedPoolThread #4 15:39:10 INFO [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline batch processing. (pipeline batch: xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync)
ManagedPoolThread #4 15:39:11 INFO [Data Exchange] No entities were read from xConnect. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Read Contacts from xConnect, pipeline step identifier: 9a2bef58-ac09-4f4d-810a-904a27f997e1, endpoint: xConnect Client Endpoint, entity: contact)
ManagedPoolThread #4 15:39:11 DEBUG [Data Exchange] 0 elements were iterated. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate xConnect Contacts and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: a1e11e8f-eb6a-438a-8bf9-09a678eced3d)
ManagedPoolThread #4 15:39:11 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Submit Remaining Dynamics Contacts in Queue, completed pipeline steps: 6)
ManagedPoolThread #4 15:39:11 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline batch processor finished processing pipelines. (pipeline batch: xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync, completed pipelines: 1)
```

1. I have contacts in xDB which is not syncing
2. Endpoints is working file
3. It was working before but stopped working now

Comment: Do tou see contacts in Experience Profile? Are thry in the index? Do tou have anonymous contacts disabled for indexing (default)?

Comment: Yes I can see contact in experience profile and  it's a known contact

Comment: Do you have any Contact Filter set for the Read Contacts from xConnect pipeline step?

Comment: No It's blank..

Comment: Could you also choose the Debug log level for the xConnect Contacts to Dynamics batch, tick the  Include Stack Trace For Exceptions check-box (https://www.screencast.com/t/EvDY3ZqP29z) and re-run import again? It can allow us to get more helpful info.

Comment: Yes it is already checked as you can see in above log message, it is showing debug log as well

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn’t noticed it. I will think what else can be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved after rebuild xConnect using below command:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXX.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker> XConnectSearchIndexer -rr
```